# How to Sort and Map an Array on Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

i have this array:

```
myArray = {
[0]{priority: 1, percent: 90, correct: true}
[1]{priority: 1, percent: 20, correct: true}
[2]{priority: 2, percent: 50, correct: true}
[3]{priority: 2, percent: 50, correct: true}
[4]{priority: 3, percent: 70, correct: true}
[5]{priority: 3, percent: 50, correct: true}
}
```

How can i add the percents by priority, and then change the value "correct" to "false" of  all the results that gave me more than 100?

for example:

- Priority 1 have 2 values: 90 and 20 = 110
- Priority 2 have 2 values: 50 and 50 = 100
- Priority 3 have 2 values: 70 and 50 = 120
- So All objects of priority 1 should change value "correct" into "false"
- All objects of priority 2 should change value "correct" into "correct"
- All objects of priority 3 should change value "correcto" into "false

Comment: yeah, but idk how to do it, can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     const myArray: { priority: number; percent: number; correct: boolean }[] = [
  { priority: 1, percent: 90, correct: true },
  { priority: 1, percent: 20, correct: true },
  { priority: 2, percent: 50, correct: true },
  { priority: 2, percent: 50, correct: true },
  { priority: 3, percent: 70, correct: true },
  { priority: 3, percent: 50, correct: true },
];
   




 const newArr = myArray
      .sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority)
      .map((val, i, myArray) => {
        const percentSum = myArray
          .filter((a) => a.priority == val.priority)
          .map((b) => b.percent)
          .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        const arrObj = {
          ...val,
          correct: percentSum > 100 ? false : true,
        };
        return arrObj;
      });

    console.log(newArr);
```

Output

```
[{
  correct: false,
  percent: 90,
  priority: 1
}, {
  correct: false,
  percent: 20,
  priority: 1
}, {
  correct: true,
  percent: 50,
  priority: 2
}, {
  correct: true,
  percent: 50,
  priority: 2
}, {
  correct: false,
  percent: 70,
  priority: 3
}, {
  correct: false,
  percent: 50,
  priority: 3
}]
```

Comment: the problem is i want to keep the 6 objects of the original list, just change the "correct" value

Comment: I updated the second option in code  as well please try that.

Comment: const newArr = myArray.sort((a, b) => a - b).map((val, i, myArray) => {
  const percentSum = myArray.filter((a) => a.priority == val.priority).map((b) => b.percent).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  const arrObj = {
    ...val,
    correct: percentSum > 100 ? false : 'correct',

  }
  return arrObj;
})

console.log(newArr);

Comment: its give me error in the const newArr = myArray.sort((a, b) => a - b).map((val, i, myArray), in the a-b part. its say: The right-hand side of an aritmethic operation mus be type "any",number, bigint or an enum type

Comment: I fixed and its working! ty very much!

Comment: Great, I also updated the code.

Comment: hey! do u have like 5 minutes to a meet on discord? i find another error, its possible?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @FelipeRomanZegers  Drop me a message on my https://twitter.com/abhiipure1289 once you are available. we can connect.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a quick solution but there could be lot of better solutions as well :

```js
myArray = [
{priority: 1, percent: 90, correct: true},
{priority: 1, percent: 20, correct: true},
{priority: 2, percent: 50, correct: true},
{priority: 2, percent: 50, correct: true},
{priority: 3, percent: 70, correct: true},
{priority: 3, percent: 50, correct: true},
];

tempMap = new Map();

myArray.forEach( (item) => {
  if(tempMap.has(item.priority)) {
    tempMap.set(item.priority, tempMap.get(item.priority) + item.percent);
  }
  else {
    tempMap.set(item.priority, item.percent);
  }
});

myArray.forEach( (item) => {
  item.correct = tempMap.get(item.priority) > 100 ? false : true;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: its dosnt work for me, trow me an exception [object Object]

Comment: Click on run code snippet, its fully functional